# How does Tor's second node know the key to decript the second layer?

Tags: networking, internet, encryption, tor, decryption

I was watching this video explaining how tor works: https://youtu.be/QRYzre4bf7I

It explains it with the example of 3 intermediate nodes between client and server. It says that each of the nodes can only decrypt one layer and therefore only the last node can see the message. Each node has only one key to decrypt the corresponding layer. My question is: how is that possible?

How can node 2 know key2 unless it's given to it by node 1? But if node one sends key then it means that node one can also decrypt the second layer.

Answer (score 1):

> if node one sends key then it means that node one can also decrypt the second layer

The nodes use a *key exchange protocol* (Diffie-Hellman specifically) to agree on a key without actually transmitting it. The DH key-exchange messages can be seen by other nodes but don't reveal enough information for them to guess the key. See [Tor protocol specification](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/tor-spec.txt), specifically the 'EXTEND' packets.

The same DH algorithm is also used for key exchange in TLS (HTTPS), SSH, IPsec, WireGuard, etc.

With DH, you still need to ensure that intermediate nodes don't *replace* the key-exchange messages with their own, usually by adding digital signatures with a key that your peer already knows. For this, TLS uses server certificates (verified by name+CA), SSH uses hostkeys (verified by fingerprint), and Tor uses [identity keys](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/tor-spec.txt#n224) that are published in the Tor relay directory.